# What kind of technology would be needed to create force fields like those from Star Trek?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, far-future

Force fields does not seem to be as surreal as the matter replicator or even teleportation or 3d holograms but I feel the workings behind it are hard to understand. I believe that to create stable force fields that could be activated anywhere that could take several different shapes require the manipulation of subatomic particles rather than atoms. How could they be manipulated to create a sci fi force field?

Comment: Unfortunately, force fields are fantasy devices with no basis in reality.

Comment: Applied phlebotinum, handwavium and reverse polarity quantum fields.

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, is magic. There are potentially forcefield _like_ things that have usefulness in scifi situations, but they're so far removed from classic science-fantasy depictions of "energy shields" that I can't really make an answer about them to this particular question.

Comment: To answer this question you need to tell us how Star Trek style force fields work in your world. Then we could help you figure out what technology is required to make that happen. Without that information the best we can do for you is the tautological "You need a forcefield generator to create a forcefield".

Comment: Thank you @SanrineCrystal, you will need to give more info on what you want the force fields to do before this can be answered. “Star Trek” uses many different force fields throughout the many years. Focus this question on one detailed problem (what do you want to deflect and where is the field working). Maybe some science theory could be offered then.

Comment: *"Force fields does not seem to be as surreal as the matter replicator or even teleportation or 3d holograms"* ? You do realise that we actually have 3d holograms right?  that they are 3d is kind of the whole point of holograms in the real world  so I think you probably mean something else, like how they appear to be solid in the show 

Comment: Just a general reminder to folks who are replying with "no basis in reality", "unfortunately, magic", and "just make some shit up" kinds of answers: it's really not our job to tell people that it can't be done! It's our actual job here to come up with the fictional sciences and procedures and to define the undefinable. I agree that the OP did not write the question very well, but that should only prompt us to respond with something like "as written, we can't really give you good answer, but if you do this and that, your questions will be much better"! "Can't be done" is beneath our creativity!

Comment: Sabrine, the proper way to ask this question would be, "I would like to implement Star Trek-styled force fields in my world. The rules I have in place so far are X, but I'm having trouble explaining the fields due to Y. What can I do to make Y conform with my rules X?" Please remember, this Stack's purpose is to help you build your fictional world - not to express fictional (and fanciful) ideas in the real world.

Comment: @elemtilas The issue is, it is under the science-based tag ^^". We can't stray much in answers from reality and the given elements. I agree with JBH, we'd have to make up some rules, however we shouldn't make all of them; This'd be more worldbuilding for them than helping them on a worldbuilding issue.

Comment: @Tortliena -- I agree with JBH as well. My point is simply that "Science based" doesn't mean "if it's not in this year's edition of Quantum Astrology then it can't be done". It simply means that the respondent must either explain with current science or if this is not possible, devise a new division of science or a new principle of existing of science that will provide the answer. I agree with you as well, in that a science based approach ought to provide a plausible, substantive and rational explanation. As I see it, attitudes like "unfortunately, magic" are needlessly limiting & dismissive.

Comment: @elemtilas That's not exactly what the tag says : "[Science-based is] for questions that require answers based on hard science, not magic or pseudo-science." If it's hard-science (without citations, contrast to [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science)), and pseudo-sciences are forbidden, then I have an hard time picturing inventing a new division of science would work for most people, either.

Comment: @Tortliena -- I didn't say "base it on *pseudo* science"! We can extrapolate and imagine, however! The buzz not long ago was all about the (supposed) discovery of a [fifth force of nature](https://www.bbc.com/news/56643677). That's pretty astounding in real world science, yet is something that I am sure most of us have either considered or actually done in our own worldbuilding projects. The thing about hard science is that regardless of how much we know, the one constant is that we don't actually know how much we know. Every answer leads to more questions, more unknowns. (cont)

Comment: (cont) This is what I'm getting at with the negative attitudes. The are too prescriptive. Realistically, if the OP wants to know how to make a ST-like force field that is based on the current understanding of science, then they should be directed to the relevant science forum. "Based on hard science", in our forum, doesn't mean we eradicate the imaginative or the creative. That tag really only ought to guide the responses, not preclude them.

Answer (score 1):

Data teleportation: https://jqi.umd.edu/news/first-teleportation-between-distant-atoms.htm can use it for reconstructing the matter later on, as printing improves

3d display: https://newatlas.com/burton-true-3d-laser-plasma-display/20499/ , i assume you mean it, rather than actual hologram, that is a 2d surface that behaves like 3d display, that we also have but not as quickly to change yet, and probably not what you ment.

But force field is a completely magical thing. No known tech leads to it. More so, almost any handwavy tech in sci-fy is closer to reality than a force field.

Gravity on board? Spin gravity, alcubiere drive, magnetic boots...

Jump drive? Wormhole, casimir effect string, alcubiere drive, probably spinning black holes...

Lazer? Lazer

See, lots of sci-fi stuff is somewhat close to real worls counterparts, or at least something similar can be done.

With force fields - no. Nothing similar. Probably tiny smart flying drones could work somewhat. But thats definitely not what you expect.

Comment: *"almost any handwavy tech in sci-fy is closer to reality than a force field."* You mean almost any ***other*** handwavy tech that can be found in sci to right?

Comment: @Pelinore yes, 'any X1 is closer to Y than X2' usually means that X2 is not included in X1

Comment: The link in the first paragraph goes to a mess of an article, which only shows that its author has no idea of what they are talking about. (And have a very tenous relationship with the English language.) You should stop visiting that site.

Comment: @AlexP good point. Replaced the link with the one that seems to know a bit more about the experiment itself